# Customize the OpenAi Gym Taxi v2 Environment

Tags: openai-gym

I would like to modifiy the Taxi V2-Environment in Open AI Gym.
Is it possible to pick up 2 passengers, before I reach the destination point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible you can modify the taxi.py file in envs in the gym folder. For two passengers the number of states (state-space)  will increase from 500 (5*5*5*4) to 10,000 (5*5*5*4*5*4), 5*4 states for another(2nd) passenger. You can now modify the code accordingly. We can also increase the number of action space from 6 to 8, by adding pickup and drop for passenger 2, to keep a record of both passengers if you want.